# HTML table background not working

Tags: html

Hello I currently am helping out an organization that uses a very basic website. They lack any CSS capabilities and I have had to code purely in html (which is far from fun). However I seem to be running into a issue. Whenever I run the code on the website a table's background fails to show up.

```
table style = "background: url(image.png)"
```

This is how I coded the table, and I don't believe I made a mistake there because when I plug it into an html editor it works perfectly fine. Am I simply working with an outdated version of html? Or is what I'm asking for impossible with this website? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my code if it could clear up any confusion

```
<table style="height: 10px; border-color: #000000; background: 
url('http://i.imgur.com/2JxgSxt.jpg'), center, no-repeat; background-size: 
100%;" width="100%">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="text-align: center; width: 15%;" bgcolor=""><span style="color: 
#ffffff;"><strong>Feb.</strong></span><br />
<p><span style="color: #ffffff;"><strong>23rd-25th</strong></span></p>
</td>
<td style="width: 5%;" bgcolor=""><span style="color: #ffffff;">&nbsp;
</span></td>
<td bgcolor="">
<h2><span style="color: #ffffff;">Two-Umpire Mechanics Clinic&nbsp;</span>
</h2>
<h4><span style="color: #ffffff;">Friday-Sunday - </span></h4>
</td>
<td style="text-align: center;" bgcolor="" width="10%"><span style="color: 
#ffffff;">&nbsp;<img style="-moz-transform: scaleX(-1); -o-transform: 
scaleX(-1); -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1); transform: scaleX(-1); filter: 
FlipH;" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/6/k/K/P/5/Z/plain-left-white-
arrow-md.png" alt="" width="17" height="32" /></span></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Without seeing the markup it's impossible for us to know. Your code looks fine, and as you said, works otherwise. Answers to this question can only be guesses at best, and as such your question will likely end up being closed as *"Too Broad"*.

Comment: Works fine here: https://jsfiddle.net/ncczrdhr/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following code:

```html
<table background="http://lorempixel.com/400/200">
  <tr>
    <td>First column</td>
    <td>Second column</td>
    <td>Third column</td>
  </tr> 
  
  <tr>
    <td>First column</td>
    <td>Second column</td>
    <td>Third column</td>
  </tr> 
  
  <tr>
    <td>First column</td>
    <td>Second column</td>
    <td>Third column</td>
  </tr> 
</table>
```

Comment: This is what I needed... I really don't understand why this works, because it won't work on my html editor but it does work on my website

Comment: Maybe there's a bug or any other issue with your html editor. BTW I think, your code wasn't working because of missing single quote. This is working: `<table style=" background: url('http://lorempixel.com/400/200')">`

Comment: I don't think so. I'm leaning toward the idea that the program is using an outdated version of html

Answer (score 0):

Since you have only written psuedo code it is difficult to validate, but at the moment you are lacking quotes for the image url it should look like this

```
<table style="width: 350px; height: 350px; background: url('https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon@2.png?v=73d79a89bded')">
<tr>
    <td>My awesome content</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Note I added some static width and height just so the example is visible. You probably should not use that in production.